# MySQL How to select/list out the data name when there are 1 or more same information within the same table?

Tags: mysql

```
create database Exercise;

use Exercise;

create table Employee (
    employee_id int(5), 
    employee_name varchar(30), 
    join_date date
);

create table Customer (
    customer_id int(5), 
    customer_name varchar(30), 
    cust_join_date date default '2012-12-06', 
    employee_id int(5)
);

alter table Employee add constraint pk__emp primary key(employee_id);
alter table Customer add constraint pk__cust primary key(customer_id);
alter table Customer add constraint fk__cust foreign key(employee_id) references employee(employee_id);
alter table Employee add (emp_age int(3),emp_gender char(1));
alter table Customer modify column customer_name varchar(1000);

insert into Employee values (0001,'Aabrara','2014-02-01',20,'M');
insert into Employee values (0002,'Babara','2015-02-02',21,'F');
insert into Employee values (0003,'Crabrara','2015-02-03',30,'F');
insert into Employee values (0004,'Drabara','2014-02-04',23,'M');
insert into Employee values (0005,'Earbrara','2014-02-05',28,'F');

insert into Customer values (1000,'Fabara','2015-02-06',0001);
insert into Customer values (2000,'Gabare','2015-02-07',0002);
insert into Customer values (3000,'Habari','2015-02-08',0002);
insert into Customer values (4000,'Iabaro','2015-02-09',0004);
insert into Customer values (5000,'Jabaru','2015-02-10',0005);
```

Above are the tables, the question is '**Find employee id and employee name who's handling more than one customer**'. How to do this?! I've been told to use sub-query but I still can't manage to solve it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where specifically do you have problems? Please add some code or ideas to the question.

Comment: select Employee.employee_id,Employee.employee_name from Employee,Customer where Employee.employee_id=Customer.employee_id in
(select count(Customer.employee_id) from Customer group by employee_id having count(Customer.employee_id)>1); this is my code, although it have no error but the result is not what the question want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `Employees`.`employee_id`, `Employees`.`employee_name`
FROM `Employees`
INNER JOIN `Customers` USING (`employee_id`)
GROUP BY `Employees`.`employee_id`
HAVING (COUNT(`Customers`.`customer_id`) > 1)
ORDER BY `Employees`.`employee_name`
```

Comment: Oh my~ thanks!!! actually I'm a newbie of mysql, haven't learnt about 'inner join' and 'using', but I'll try figure out now, thanks again XD

Comment: Good deal.

Let me warn you about a couple of things, though.
 - Some database engines (like MS SQL Server) will require that every column that is selected or part of the `ORDER BY` clause must be in the `GROUP BY` clause. What you see above is a MySQL shortcut.
 - The `USING` keyword is another MySQL shortcut. The code above is a shortcut for the following:

    ON (`Customers`.`employee_id` = `Employees`.`employee_id`)

Comment: @Lexonss If this answer worked for you, please flag it as the accepted answer. Thanks!